# Issue related to the rect data in SVG

Tags: svg, inkscape

I'm currently writing a parser for SVG for a project I'm working on. I'm using inkscape as the editor
[image]

And the plain SVG I get from inkscape is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   width="256"
   height="256"
   viewBox="0 0 25.6 25.6"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg5"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs
     id="defs2" />
  <rect
     style="fill:#800080;stroke-width:0.0566834"
     id="rect122"
     width="10.274419"
     height="9.6836576"
     x="10.734594"
     y="-6.7066712"
     transform="matrix(0.84492681,0.53488194,-0.51677089,0.85612373,0,0)" />
</svg>
```

My question is, what does the x and y of rect tag mean exactly in this context?
I'm also confused as to why the y-coordinate is negative?

Comment: So, I think its supposed to represent transformed coordinates
To get the original coordinates, you've to untransform it back

I still want clarification on whether I'm right about it this though

Comment: Those are untransformed coordinates using viewBox units. You have to multiple them by the transform matrix to get the rendered coordinates. If there was no transform matrix, the origin of this rect would be 107px right and 67px above the SVG origin (aka partly outside the SVG boundary). As to "why" that's the case - SVG editors (Illustrator, Inkscape) often use transforms to resize & move stuff around rather than rewriting the x,y,height.width. And I don't know why that's the case.

Comment: My editor (I use affinity designer but Im sure InkScape supports it too) allows you to require 'relative coordinates' on export, which will apply all transforms as much as possible. Maybe thats a solution?

Comment: @somethinghere I'm not sure of any such export features in inkscape, but maybe I need to look a bit more into they're website to know about it. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelMullany Ah, I see, I was quite puzzled about it for a while especially when not finding anything online about it, and actually thinking about it, the way it transforms the coordinate seems odd.
But even so, the issue is resolved. Thanks!

Comment: The `x` and `y` attributes are the position of the top left of the rectangle **before** the `transform` is applied.  That particular `transform` represents a rotation.  The translation x and y values of the matrix are zero, so we know it has been rotated around the default origin of the SVG.   That's at (0,0). So effectively the rectangle is mostly off the page. But the matrix has rotated it back onto the page in the displayed location.

Answer (score 1):

Animation showing the original and transformed positions of the rectangle.

```css
svg {
  border: solid 1px grey;
  background: linen;
  margin: 100px 0 0 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

rect {
   animation: move 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% { transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); }
  50% { transform: matrix(0.84492681,0.53488194,-0.51677089,0.85612373,0,0); }
  100% { transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); }
}
```

```html
<svg
   width="256"
   height="256"
   viewBox="0 0 25.6 25.6"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg5"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs
     id="defs2" />
  <rect
     style="fill:#800080;stroke-width:0.0566834"
     id="rect122"
     width="10.274419"
     height="9.6836576"
     x="10.734594"
     y="-6.7066712"
     transform="matrix(0.84492681,0.53488194,-0.51677089,0.85612373,0,0)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Helpful Answer. Great Demo  the original and transformed positions of the rectangle.